# Doctrine ODM bundle document mapping in XML format

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, odm

I'm using Doctrine ODM bundle with Symfony 4.
Trying to use XML mapping format for Documents and getting the following error:

`No mapping file found named 'Post.mongodb.xml' for class 'App\Document\Post'.`

My **doctrine_mongodb.yaml** file:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    auto_generate_hydrator_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    connections:
        default:
            server: '%env(MONGODB_URL)%'
            options: {}
    default_database: '%env(MONGODB_DB)%'
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: xml
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Resources/config/doctrine'
                    prefix: App\Document\
                    alias: App
```

Document **src/Document/Post.php** file:

```
namespace App\Document;

class Post
{
    protected $id;

    protected $title;

    protected $text;

//Getters and setters
}
```

XML mapping file **src/Resources/config/doctrine/Post.mongodb.xml**:

```
<doctrine-mongo-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/odm/doctrine-mongo-mapping"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/odm/doctrine-mongo-mapping
                    http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/odm/doctrine-mongo-mapping.xsd">

    <document name="App\Document\Post">
        <field fieldName="id" id="true" />
        <field fieldName="title" type="string" />
        <field fieldName="text" type="string" />
    </document>
</doctrine-mongo-mapping>
```

Composer configuration (require section):

`"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.1",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.5",
    "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*"
}`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was correct in my configs from the question execpt trailing slash in `prefix` value.

According to the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/xml-mapping.html#xml-mapping):

> The name of the mapping document must consist of the fully qualified name of the class, where namespace separators are replaced by dots (.).

If you provide prefix, which is the namespace to your documents, you will get mapping file name like `Post.mongodb.xml`

Example:

- Namespace of the `Post` document `App\Document`
- Your mapping prefix `App\Document`
- Mapping filename `Post.mongodb.xml` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Name the mapping file `Post.dcm.xml`.

This convention is by [design](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/xml-mapping.html#example). For `App\Document\Namespace\Another` document it would be `Namespace.Another.dcm.xml`.

Comment: Prefix should be `App\Document`. Set auto mapping to false. Clear the cache.

Comment: After all described steps I'm getting the same error - ```No mapping file found named 'Post.mongodb.xml' for class 'App\Document\Post'.``` Maybe, XML mapping file must have ```Post.mongodb.xml``` name?

Comment: Maybe, what are your project dependencies related to the ODM?

Comment: Added composer.json configuration to my question.